# How can I make an autocomplete function for zsh that can allow for a random number?

Tags: command-line, zsh, autocomplete

I have a small script for managing tickets in gitlab repos. When I type ticket and press tab, I'd like to see:

```
% ticket
new  -- create a new ticket
#    -- Number of ticket
-v   -- increase verbosity
```

To do this I've done this which doesn't work:

```
#compdef ticket
#autoload

local -a reply

_regex_words commands "ticket commands" \
  'new:create a new ticket' \
  '-v:increase verbosity' \
  '[1-9][0-9]#:open ticket #'
_regex_arguments _ticket /$'[^\0]##\0'/ "${reply[@]}"

_ticket "$@"
```

I get that it can't complete the number in my brain - nor do I want it going out and loading up possibly thousands of numbers. But noting that a number is a possible completion would be good.

Answer (score 1):

The `_regex_words` function is meant for use with literal words, not with patterns (aside from a single `*` where words can be abbreviated). So you'll need to handle the number from `_regex_arguments` directly – something like the following:

```
#compdef ticket

local -a reply

_regex_words commands "ticket commands" \
  'new:create a new ticket' \
  '-v:increase verbosity'

_regex_arguments _ticket /$'[^\0]##\0'/ \
  \( "${reply[@]}" \
  \| $'/[1-9][0-9]#\0/' ': _message -e numbers "open ticket"' \)

_ticket "$@"
```

It's a bit ugly that this needs `_message`. That's a side-effect of how it is implemented via `_alternative` but there are examples of this style elsewhere. If you've got many normal options like `-v`, it can be better to use `_arguments` for those and only use `_regex_arguments` for more complicated areas.

By the way, you `#autoload` tag is superfluous. `compinit` looks at the first line only and either `#autoload` or `#compdef` will cause it to be marked as autoloadable.